# How long should I wait before making a Facebook query with FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm using FQL to query posts from a facebook page and sometimes randomly get an error saying: "The remote (facebook) server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error".

The way I handle this is by Sleeping the thread for about 3 seconds. But I was curious if there is a recommended amount of time to wait before querying with FQL if it fails the first time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hard rules on this. You can do an increasing back-off mechanism.

- Try first
- If failed, wait 1 second and try again
- If failed again, wait 3 seconds and try again

Until you reach a maximum of perhaps 3/4 attempts.